# Unable to cast Object to type Interval typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object  `a` which has lots of properties inside. On edit I save these properties and one of them is `interval`. Later I assign it to other property (`typedObject`) Everything works fine. Then I click edit and do not change the `interval`  and then I try to assign it to `typedObject` but it somehow shows that it's an `Object` and not the type of `Interval`. I try to  cast it to type of `Interval` like:

`const typedObject: Interval = a.interval as Interval;`

also tried: `const typedObject: Interval = <Interval>a.interval;`

But it `typedObject` is still Object. Why is that happening?

I need to use function which only exists for type `Interval` and I get exception when  I call `typedObject.getRange();`

`Interval` is a class.

I get error:
`Uncaught TypeError: a.interval.getRange is not a function`

It works if I do:

```js
        let typedObject = new IntervalRange();
        typedObject.day = a.interval.day;
        typedObject.month = a.interval.month;
        typedObject.quarter = a.interval.quarter;
        typedObject.timezone = a.interval.timezone;
      
        const from = <Interval>typedObject.getRange().from;
        const to = <Interval>typedObject.getRange().to;
```

But assigning `typedObject.quarter = a.interval.quarter;` one by one doesn't look very clean

Comment: Could you show us the exception you get, and how you are testing the typedObject type ? Are you using `typeof` ? Is Interval a Class or an Interface ?

Comment: Please, post all the relevant code

Comment: Unless you've called `new Interval()` somewhere `a.interval` is an object literal, not an `Interval` instance.

Comment: @TheHeadRush where should I call it?

Comment: Before you call `getRange`. Not intending to sound snippy but without code (or context) there's not much more to say.